# PHP local server form submit working fine. In live Server Not working

Tags: php

Query 1.
       form submitting working fine in local , but not working in live. I removed the action and put # and also i didn't call any script for redirect but while click the submit button it is automatically redirect to the same page. i don't know how it is redirecting ? 
   Query 2. 
       In action i mentioned `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` and also gave direct url . if i print the post value it is not coming to POST .

In both ways it is showing the error

> This page isn’t working
>   www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com didn’t send any data.

here below i paste my short code

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = rand(1000,9999);
include("./config/dbconnect.php");
include("./functions/functions.php");

if($_POST){
    print_r($_POST); exit;
}
?>
 <table border="0" width="100%"><tr><td style="padding-left:25px">
                        <form name="register" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          <table width="634" border="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td  colspan="3" class="sub_heading"><div align="right"><span class="style_r">* Mandatory Fields</span></div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td height="24"  colspan="3"><div align="left" class="sub_heading">Login Information</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="178">Email<span class="style_r">*</span></td>
                              <td width="10">:</td>
                              <td width="432"><input type="text" name="email" width="14" maxlength="50" /></td>
                            </tr> ******************* etc <tr>
                              <td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" name="terms" />
                                I have read, understood and agree to the <a href="terms.php" class="job_links" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> of eGulfCareers.com</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="178"></td>
                              <td width="10"></td>
                              <td width="432"><input type="hidden" name="register" value="1" />
                                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signup" class="submit_button" /></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </form></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>        `
```

Comment: remove '#' from action...

Comment: i tried that too but not working.

Comment: It worked for me (as is, excluding the include lines) Array ( [email] => test@test.com [register] => 1 [submit] => Signup )

Comment: @roetnig did you tried in live server? because local everything working fine but in live if click the submit button suddenly redirecting i cannot to debug

Comment: Local and remote. It worked ok

Comment: try
if(!empty($_POST)){
print_r($_POST);
}

Comment: and for debug
first remove this code then submit your form

ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = rand(1000,9999);
include("./config/dbconnect.php");
include("./functions/functions.php");

Comment: HI thanx for your replies finally i found my error. i have document uploading in my form if i upload doc or docx it will immediately shows error but for pdf jpg file uploading it is working fine it is redirecting to next page. i got error but i dont know the solution?

Comment: if i upload the ms word file it shows the error that is the problem pls tell me the solution?

Comment: I don't see any file in the form you posted...

Comment: Hi i just shorted my code. ' <tr>
                                  <td width="178">Attach CV<span class="style_r">*</span></td>
                                  <td width="10">:</td>
                                  <td width="432"><input type="file" name="msword_cv" width="14" />
                                  </td>
                                </tr>' this is the upload file code